# convert date into day of year in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

Got a query!
In the given data frame, there is entire column DDAY containing date

```
   DDAY MM  YYYY
    8   1   1975
    7   2   1978
    14  4   2000
    4   5   2013
    13  10  2018
```

What is the fastest approach to convert it into day of year?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select only columns for convert to datetimes, `rename` them, so working [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with `day, month, year` columns and last add [`Series.dt.dayofyear`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.dayofyear.html):

```
d = {'DDAY':'day','MM':'month','YYYY':'year'}
df['new'] = pd.to_datetime(df[['DDAY','MM','YYYY']].rename(columns=d)).dt.dayofyear
print (df)
   DDAY  MM  YYYY  new
0     8   1  1975    8
1     7   2  1978   38
2    14   4  2000  105
3     4   5  2013  124
4    13  10  2018  286
```

Comment: Since above given data frame is a small set from my original data frame, while running your code, i am getting ```cannot assemble the datetimes: time data '19841000' does not match format '%Y%m%d' (match)```

Comment: @AyushiNema - so there is wrong day `00` ?